# C# How to populate data grid view by the use of datagridview_comboboxes

Tags: c#, datagridview

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XCFRH.png)

In the above image I would like to read the value assigned to the material combobox and populate the rest of the table based on that selection. Right now that happens by clicking the Update button. Is it possible for the population to take place right after the selection of the combobox by skipping the update button ?

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Please take some time to review the [tour] and [ask]. Please add relevant details, ideally a [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

The combo box element has an event that fires when the selection changed (ComboBox.SelectedIndexChanged event https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.combobox.selectedindexchanged?view=netframework-4.8)

If you bind a method to this event, the method will be executed whenever the selection changes. 
You can get the desired behavior by binding the method that is currently bound to your button.Click event to the ComboBox.SelectedIndexChanged event.

Comment: A [DataGridViewComboboxColumn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcomboboxcolumn?view=netframework-4.8) has no such event

Comment: I think the same. So you think that i cannot save me from the update button?